# how to extract single element from a bag in pig?

Tags: bigdata, extract, apache-pig, bag, complex-data-types

My pig statement generates the following output:

```
({(10)},5201)
({(20),(20),(20)},3334)
({(30),(30),(30),(30)},4632)
({(40),(40)},3101)
({(50),(50)},3801)
({(60),(60),(60)},3959)
```

But I want to store above output as below in pig:

```
(10,5201)
(20,3334)
(30,4632)
(40,3101)
(50,3801)
(60,3959)
```

Is there any way to extract the very first element from bag in pig?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Datafu UDF [FirstTupleFromBag](http://datafu.incubator.apache.org/docs/datafu/1.2.0/datafu/pig/bags/FirstTupleFromBag.html) to achieve exactly this!